# code push to heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, deployment

I want to push code on heroku that is on gihub

I used the following command

```
git push heroku mybranch:master
```

The error is

```
To https://github.com/user/lyricle-new.git
 ! [rejected]        lyricle-frt-backend -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Used the command `git pull` as mentioned in hint the response was `Already up-to-date.`

What could be the reasons behind this error? and is this the correct way to push on heroku

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `git push heroku mybranch:master`, you are telling git to take your **local** `mybranch` branch and merge it with the **remote** `master` branch (remotely stored on your heroku repo).
You get an error because `master` is ahead of `mybranch` in terms of commits.

Consider this example:
`master: --------b---------m---------

 mybranch:........\-c--c--/...........`

At some point, you branch (**b**) master into mybranch, commit (**c**) some code to the branch, and merge (**m**) it back to master.

Now consider this example:
`master: --c-----b---c-----m---c--

 mybranch:........\-c--c---/.......`

It is pretty much the same scenario but while you were committing code to `mybranch`, someone updated `master` by committing some other code. If you were to merge back `mybranch` into `master`, you would risk causing conflicts between your code and the new code contained in `master`, thus Git refuses to do the merge. First, you have to update your local branch with the new version of `master` and then only Git will allow you to push.

**In short:**
- `git pull heroku master:mybranch`
- *resolve potential conflicts*
- *commit modified files*
- `git push heroku mybranch:master`

---

Now about Heroku, you are supposed to always push code like this: `git push heroku master` (considering you are on the `master` branch locally). What you should do to avoid things like `git push heroku mybranch:master` is, when you finish working on a branch, always merge your changes to `master` and then (after verifying that everything is working) push master to heroku.

See this resource for a simple git workflow that seem to be what you are looking for: https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch

Everything is centralized in master eventually, and you can then regularly push master to heroku (ideally you would push once for every version of your app)

Comment: If, like me, you have two Heroku apps (for production and staging), make sure your local `staging` branch is up-to-date with your `master` branch before attempting a `git push staging staging:master`

Answer (score 0):

From the hints it seems that you have not pushed your latest changes to your remote repository.if you have done a pull and pushed again maybe you have removed files in your local repository that you did not remove in your remote repository.try doing a git add --all and then commit and push the changes.