# Can't push to Heroku (non-fast-forward) [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm having troubles pushing some code to Heroku. I'm still in the process of learning how all of these tools work, so I'm going to paste what I just did.

```
saasbook@saasbook:~/typo$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   db/db_development
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

saasbook@saasbook:~/typo$ git push origin
Username for 'https://github.com': FranGoitia
Password for 'https://FranGoitia@github.com': 
To https://github.com/FranGoitia/typo
   3b2d868..02c6eb1  master -> master
saasbook@saasbook:~/typo$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   db/db_development
#
saasbook@saasbook:~/typo$ git push heroku master
To https://git.heroku.com/still-ravine-4135.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/still-ravine-4135.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
saasbook@saasbook:~/typo$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': FranGoitia
Password for 'https://FranGoitia@github.com': 
Everything up-to-date
saasbook@saasbook:~/typo$ git push heroku master
To https://git.heroku.com/still-ravine-4135.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/still-ravine-4135.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
saasbook@saasbook:~/typo$
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push origin master
To https://github.com/Joey-project/project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Joey-project/project.git'
```

has been discussed here before. It's a common error.

A main reason of this happening is because one should not push his/her branch to an updated remote branch.

If I remember correctly, one has to use something similar like:

```
git fetch origin; git merge origin/master
```

[code push to heroku not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247808) might come in handy, which has a lot of extra information regarding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used heroku CLI long back, so I dont remember much, but by the looks of it, the issue is because you did not fetch merge it.

This might have caused due to the change of git files in heroku separately. Meaning, say I work on my local copy, push it to the origin(on git) , but while doing this, if I had made changes to the git files on heroku, when you try to push the new changes from the local system, it is going to cause this error. In other words, the flow is disrupted.Git gets confused. It rejects.

so first, fetch merge from heroku(dont even know if its possible, it should be though) , then if there are conflicts, remove them manually, now code has heroku changes and also your recent changes leveled out,  now push them to heroku. It should work.